# Angular ui-router states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

im having a problem about states, i will demostrate(more easy to explain):
1º View

```
<div class="left-side">
    <div >
         <div>Channel List</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mid-side">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
<div class="right-side">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

When I click on an item from the list of channels, this triggers a state change that will load a view on the mid side (that part works fine). example URL: /?Channel=123

But i want to, when someone clicks on something on the mid side (inside ui-view) to load a view on the right side, example URL: /?Channel=123&Extra=1.

The issue is that when this happens, the mid side also reloads. How can I only load the right side given that will trigger a state change (URL changes from /?Channel=123 to /?Channel=123&Extra=1)

Thanks.

Comment: unclear question ...

Comment: You may want to look at using named views; https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle demo case.

Comment: and also nested/child states so that a particular state opens within a specific tab, named views so you can tell your other states where their views should be rendored